# What's the role of "denn" here?

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german

I was watching [Folge 03](https://youtu.be/VfDOzaihbH8?t=169) and they said:

> Ab wann kann man denn Talent erkennen?

I understood the question, but what is *denn* doing here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_particle

Comment: If only that link (or the link in it) said anything about "denn"

Comment: It is a modal particle. There are lots of questions with good answers about this topic here: http://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Modalpartikel

Comment: How is this a duplicate? Wouldn't we expect different modal particles to do different thinks? (After all, I couldn't very well say "Ab wann kann man doch Talent erkennen?") I suggest to reopen this question.

Answer (score 6):

In questions 'denn' is often a matter of emphasizing, suggesting a nuance of scepticism or reservation. In your case the question might suggest doubt that talent can be recognised at all.

A nearly synonym sentence would be "Ab wann kann man Talent überhaupt erkennen?" A proper translation to english might be "When can we recognize talent at all?"

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the elusive German *Abtönungspartikeln*. If you use it in a question, the implication is that you are questioning a subtly more general point than the one that was under discussion before. Example:

> Ich finde Cindy ziemlich talentlos. = I think Cindy isn't very talented.

This is a statement about an individual.

> Und Bert? = What about Bert?

This is a question about another individual.

But with *denn*:

> Woran erkennt man denn Talent? = What is talent, anyway?

This moves the discussion in a more general direction.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (and I am a native speaker) that *denn* here indicates that the speaker considers the fact that after some point talent can be recognised as a given. (Also it seems more natural if there has been a previous utterance to that effect.) The same utterance without *denn* sounds a lot less connected with what has been said before (It could be the title of a book, for instance), while with *denn* it seems to relate to the context.